# TPL Task progress in modal dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, task-parallel-library

Say I have a long running Task that I want to run, and that can notify the user interface of its status/progress. The catch here is that the UI I want is a modal dialog, and I can't show it before I start the task, nor can I start the task and then show it.

Attempt 1: show dialog first, then start task:

```
ProgressDialog dlg = new ProgressDialog();
Task longRunningTask = CreateTask();  
dlg.ShowDialog();
longRunningTask.Start();
Task.WaitAll(longRunningTask);
```

Which obviously doesn't work, the thread is blocked at ShowDialog() and the task will never start.

Attempt 2: start task, then show dialog:

```
ProgressDialog dlg = new ProgressDialog();
Task longRunningTask = CreateTask();  
longRunningTask.Start();
dlg.ShowDialog();
Task.WaitAll(longRunningTask);
```

But in this scenario I risk missing the first progress events from the task, or worse, I get the dreaded cross-thread exception raised when "InvokeRequired" says false because the first events arrive to the progress dialog while it is being created, but been shown yet so it has no handle.

I suppose I could pass the task into the dialog and have the dialog start it, but it feels like there is an elegant solution to this problem that doesn't require that?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395379/tracking-progress-of-a-multi-step-task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Shown` event is perfect for solving this problem:

```
ProgressDialog dlg = new ProgressDialog();
dlg.Shown += (_, args) =>
{
    CreateTask().Start();
};
dlg.ShowDialog();
```

If you need to ensure that the task has finished before moving on, and the form might be closed before it's done, you can modify it to wait on the task like so:

```
ProgressDialog dlg = new ProgressDialog();
Task longRunningTask = CreateTask();
dlg.Shown += (_, args) =>
{
    longRunningTask.Start();
};
dlg.ShowDialog();
longRunningTask.Wait();
```

Note that in both cases here the dialog form is created before the task is created, so you can pass the `dlg` instance to `CreateTask` if to allow it to access the instance of the form.